# GitBlit behind nginx keeps adding superfluous /gitblit/ on login/logout operations

Tags: nginx, tomcat

I set up Gitblit within Tomcat on a server. I want it to be accessible via `https://git.mydomain.tld`. So far, this works but it has one little quirk. Whenever a user logs in to Gitblit, it redirects to `https://git.mydomain.tld/gitblit/;jsessionid=...` and Tomcat returns a 404 (of course).

I added a gitblit_ssl configuration to nginx which looks as follows:

```
server {
    listen   git.mydomain.tld:443; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    server_name git.mydomain.tld;
    root        /var/www;

    # left out SSL-Configuration

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8081/gitblit/;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    }

    location /gitblit {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8081/gitblit/;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    }
}
```

Apache Tomcat is set to handle HTTP-Traffic on Port 8081 and gitblit is deployed to `webapps/gitblit`.

The "location /gitblit" I added at the end was my attempt at trying to catch the unneccessary /gitblit, but it doesn't help.

Aside from the glitch at login, everything else works as expected, but after login I have to remove the unnecessary /gitblit from the URL to use the web interface.

Comment: On http://gitblit.com/properties.html I see you can setup a canonical URL, what value do you have on  web.canonicalUrl = in your config file ?

Comment: I don't have access to the machine right now, but it sounds very reasonable that this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately setting the canonical URL doesn't solve the issue, I keep getting an additional /gitblit/

Comment: too bad, I added my anwser as I found a way to do it, though you have to change the conf or your tomcat a little bit

Answer (score 0):

On this gitlib git [issue](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/issues/431#issuecomment-130270739) I found that you add

```
<Host name="gitblit" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
          xmlValidation="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Context path="" docBase="gitblit" reloadable="true" privileged="true"
          antiResourceLocking="false" anitJARLocking="false"/>
</Host>
```

You should already have a localhost Host defined in `conf/server.xml`

So it makes your gitlib the root app at http://gitblit:8081/ for example, where hostname is the dns of your server. So I guess localhost in your case.

Once this is done you can adapt your proxy config in nginx like so :

```
location / {
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8081/;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
}
```

I installed and setup gitlib (war) like this on tomcat 7 and it works.